# Lync 2010 Save my Lync contacts in my personal contacts folder on the exchange server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010, lync-2010

Currently all of our users are using a global policy with Lync 2010 that sets the option "EnableExchangeContactSync" to false. This means that within the Lync client properties, the option "Save my Lync contacts in my personal contacts folder on the exchange server" is greyed out. However, we have one user that has this box checked although it is greyed out. Therefore, we are not able to to uncheck the option. I have run

Get-CsClientPolicy | where-object {$_.EnableExchangeContactSync -eq $True}

to see if there is another policy configured in our environment however nothing was returned.

Does anyone have an idea where this setting is getting pulled from for this user or if there is a way that we can reset this setting for a particular user?

Thanks,

Krubb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a cmdlet to do this system wide, `Set-CsClientPolicy -EnableExchangeContactSync $false` why not try this on the user and see if that rectifies the problem?

If this approach (the Set-CSClientPolicy overwrite) doesn't work, try patching the user's Lync version.  I've heard of this patch, [KB2880980](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880980), resolving an issue with jacked up client policy settings.

One last thing that points to needing to update the client, as seen in [this TechNet Thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/lync/en-US/bcc40f19-0008-4bfd-97c3-cfe3b991caf1/enableexchangecontactsync-set-to-false-not-working?prof=required):

> let's bring this to top again, because there is still an annoying bug within the latest versions of the client (.7577.4103 and .7577.4098).
>
> If you use EnableExchangeContactSync and set it to $false, the checkbox on the client gets greyed out (.enabled=false in VB), but NOT the value of the checkbox. So the contacts are still being synced with your Outlook, and you can't change the value of the checkbox because it is greyed out.
>
> If you want to disable syncing the contacts you have to do the following: set EnableExchangeContactSync to $True, uncheck the checkbox within your client (once per user), and then set EnableExchangeContactSync to $False again.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I've checked the version of Lync and we are on 7.577.4446 and the KB you mentioned isn't installed. One thing I am not sure of is how to apply that particular setting to a single individual. I ran the command you suggested on my workstation and while it showed EnableExchangeContactSync=True the box was still greyed out. I did try logging out of Lync and back in again but that didn't change anything. I've since reset back to FALSE as I was concerned that change was applied globally and not just local to me.

Comment: While I am still not sure if running the command Set-CSClientPolicy only impacted the individual I was working with or that temporarily affected the global policy, that did fix my issue. I was able to set to $TRUE and then uncheck the box that had been greyed out and checked already. I then reset back to $FALSE. Thank you for the assistance!!